# Show that $e^{\theta(s\times)} = I + \sin\theta(s\times) + (1 − \cos \theta)(s\times)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cross-product

$$e^{\theta(s\times)} = I + \sin\theta(s\times) + (1 − \cos \theta)(s\times)^2$$

I have to prove the above formula and am not sure where to start, may someone please help me! The full question is posted on this link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNGmM.jpg

$(s\times)$ is the skew operator and it is defined below, it pretty much is the cross product

$$s\times \triangleq \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&-c_s&b_s\\c_s&0&-a_s\\-b_s&a_s&0
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Computing $(s\times)^2$ and $(s\times)^3$ would be a good start. If you don't see it yet, compute a few more powers.

Comment: I used matlab to compute them but the matrices just get bigger and bigger I am not sure how to simplify it to get an answer. I know that matrix exponentials expand like taylor polynomials but I can't seem to connect that with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is true only when $s$ is a unit vector. The key is that $(s\times)^3=-(s\times)$. For convenience, write $K=(s\times)$. Then
\begin{align*}
e^{\theta K}
&=I+\theta K+\frac1{2!}\theta^2K^2+\frac1{3!}\theta^3K^3+\frac1{4!}\theta^4K^4
+\frac1{5!}\theta^5K^5+\frac1{6!}\theta^6K^6+\ldots\\
&=I+\theta K+\frac1{2!}\theta^2K^2-\frac1{3!}\theta^3K-\frac1{4!}\theta^4K^2
+\frac1{5!}\theta^5K+\frac1{6!}\theta^6K^2+\ldots\\
&=I+\left(\theta-\frac1{3!}\theta^3+\frac1{5!}\theta^5-\ldots\right)K
+\left(\frac1{2!}\theta^2-\frac1{4!}\theta^4
+\frac1{6!}\theta^6+\ldots\right)K^2
\end{align*}
and the result follows.

Comment: How are the negatives being introduced in this equation? Normally the imaginary becomes the negatives but this equation doesn't have an imaginary component?

Comment: @will This has been explained right at the beginning: the key is that $K^3=-K$.

Comment: But how do you prove that key?

Comment: @will Just calculate $K^3$ directly! For generic $a,b,c$, you should get $K^3=-(a^2+b^2+c^2)K$. Therefore, when $(a,b,c)^\top$ is a unit vector, we have $K^3=-K$.